# Trouble instantiating an object via init() method passing in an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift to create an NSObject by its init() method, passing in strings and an array of Dictionaries (the Dictionaries represent UIButtons, each with a title, a link, a blurb for each potential button - there can be from 1-3 of these buttons).

In the init() method of ContentItem() I'm trying to create Dictionaries as properties of this object.

It is giving me an error: "Instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type "(String: String)" on the line: "var tempButton = [String: String][]".

I did some research and it sounds like it might be to do with instantiating variables in the init() method - because this is before the object has been created?

Is this correct?  Anyone have any insight into this?  Is there a way to just map these passed in arguments to the class?  I'm stuck.  Thanks.

```
class ContentItem: NSObject {
     var title: String
     var body: String
     var buttonsArray: Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

     init?(title: String, body: String, buttonsArgs: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) {
        self.title = title
        self.body = body

        for btn in buttonsArgs {
            var tempButton = [String: String][]     // placeholder for the button we are creating to attach to buttonsArray[]
            for (btnKey, btnValue) in btn {         // iterate through each button's Dictionary element that is passed in to init()
                print("btnKey: \(btnKey), btnValue: \(btnValue)")
                tempButton[btnKey] = btnValue       // assembling the parameters of this button
            }
            self.buttonsArray.append(tempButton)    // assigning the buttons to the object
        }
        super.init()
     }
 }
```

Comment: It seems to me that Structs would be more appropriate than Dictionaries here

Comment: Why do you create a failable initializer which can actually never fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue 1

Function calls are always done with the `( )`, not `[ ]`:

```
var tempButton = [String: String]()
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var tempButton: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary<String, String>.init()
```

## Issue 2

You're attempting to append to an array that doesn't exist:

```
var buttonsArray: Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
```

That line declares that a variable called `buttonsArray` will exist, of type `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>`, but it doesn't define any values for it. Change it to this instead:

```
var buttonsArray: Array<Dictionary<String,String>> = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
```

And now that there is an initialization occuring, the compiler can infer the type for us:

```
var buttonsArray = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
```

And we can use the shorthand for `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>`, `[[String : String]]`;

```
var buttonsArray = [[String : String]]()
```

Comment: I tried that, but it then gives me an error "Variable self.buttonsArray passed by reference before being initialized." on the line self.buttonsArray.append(tempButton).  Which, when I investigated this, I was guided to change what you pointed out to the square brackets because it isn't being initialized or something.  It also then says "Property self.buttonsArray not initialized at super.init() call."  So that doesn't seem to work.  What do these errors suggest?

Comment: Those errors aren't caused by my answer, they're a consequence of the compiler going further down its checklist now that I fixed the most pressing error.

Comment: As the compiler says, self.buttonsArray not initialized, either in your initializer, nor in the super class initializer(s). Thus, you're attempting to append to an array that doesn't exist.

Comment: You're a genius!  I get it now.  Thank you, sir.

Comment: @SH10151 Why are you using dictionaries here in the first place, if I may ask?

Comment: What would you suggest instead of Dictionaries?  Structs, as you mentioned above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116615/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-sh10151).